# c shell stuck in infinite loop

Tags: c, shell, infinite-loop

I am creating a c shell and having an issue where I am stuck in an infinite loop. Example input/ouput: I type "ls -a" and the results of the command continually print over and over to console. If I remove the label (I called `start:`) and the `goto` statement then my shell will just execute the command and then exit the shell program entirely. I have also tried using while(1) and for(;;) loops but these resulted in the same output I am currently getting. How can I accomplish my goal here? all help is appreciated. see code below.

```
int main( int argc, const char* argv[]){
  char whole[1024];
  int cmdCount = 1;

 start:
  scanf("%1023[^\t\n]", whole);
  //....
 goto start;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Double check your first while loop.

Comment: `if (third="")` - That's two errors at once: (1) You are assigning an empty string to `third` unconditionally. Because the empty string is not `NULL`, the copndition is false. (2) You can't compare strings with regular comparison, `==`. To test whether a string is empty, do `if (*third == '\0')`.

Comment: @M Oehm this runs fine and doesnt error. I am checking if it is empty and setting to null if it is empty

Comment: Just trust M Oehm. They're right about that part of the code.

Comment: @peggy Ignoring advice from someone who clearly knows what they are talking about is a bad idea. Why even post your question here, if you already know it all?

Comment: @Jonathan the advice wasnt ignored and I've made the change. I was bringing to his attention that he said this would error and it is currently not

Comment: He did not say it would error. He said it was incorrect.

Comment: Well, an error won't always manifest with bad behaviour during execution, especially since it is about the third "word" and your input is "ls -l". The intention of your code was clear, I just pointed out that you went about it wrongly. (And, to add a third error to my laundry list: `third`, als all other word pointers, isn't initialised, so if `cmdCount` is less than three, accessing `third` for testing is undefined behaviour. Also, I don't think that `strtok` ever produces empty tokens.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `scanf` will read everything except newline or tab. You never check if it reads anything. So the first time it succeeds, the next time there's a newline so it can't read anything. You don't check this and just use the buffer which contains the previously read line. This will cause the same command to be run over and over again.

Rather read lines from stdin and parse them, don't read with `scanf`.

Comment: do you have a suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: @peggy As I wrote, read input line at a time. fgets is your friend. And if you want to use scanf, always check the return value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you didn't check return of value of your `scanf` function. First it scans everything up to `\n` character and executes your code. But the `\n` character is still left in buffer; So next `scanf` will do nothing, leaving old `whole` value intact. That's why it's executing the same command over and over again. Check the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char whole[1024];
    strcpy(whole, "override whole string");
    scanf("%1023[^\t\n]", whole);
    printf("%s\n", whole);
    strcpy(whole, "override whole string");
    scanf("%1023[^\t\n]", whole);
    printf("%s\n", whole);

    return 0;
}
```

It won't allow you to enter two lines. Second `scanf` will just fail, leaving old "overridden" value.

Use `fgets` function to get whole lines of input.